# JQuery UI Autocomplete, value after select (by mouse) is different than (by arrow-keys)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using `jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.1` with `Jquery 1.4.2` and I have this issue.

At first, I can't force the value of the Autocomplete input field, well this is not a big problem.

But I have this issue with it:

I doesn't act similarly when a user `select` a choice using mouse to using keyboard arrows. When using keyboard everything is fine and the value appears after select in the input text box, but when using mouse it sticks with the old (typed) value not the selected one.

How to control this (textbox value after select)? and why there are different behaviours?

P.S: changing the value of the input box inside the `select` function is useless since it can't be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it in the prefect way, So I've managed to hide the search input field on `select` and display another customized `div` that is hidden on click the focus passed to the `jQuery UI` search `input` filed again.

Comment: I know this is old, but im having a similar issue. care to share a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

or you can add it in select

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#input').val(ui.item.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to this.

When using the keyboard the focus from the text box is lost, but on click the focus goes back to the text box.

It could be that you have something happening on the focus of the input field which is being re-triggered?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
   source: items,
   focus: function(event, ui) { var text = ui.item.value; 
   $('#input').val(text); 
   return false; 
   }
});
```

Hovering the item with the mouse, will fill the textbox with the current value, and when you click into it the value will be already displayed on the textbox

Answer (score 1):

The sollution was to stop event by preventDefault() inside of autocomplete focus callback